# making a ajax live load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

can anyone know how can I make this as an ajax live load?

unfortunately, I have limited acknowledge about javascript/jquery/ajax

simply I want to load the search result on ajax live load

This is my javascript code to load the data but it will refresh the page
I want to not refresh the page and load the data on live load

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function get_url() {
    var urlPrefix   = 'https://example.com/home/courses?'
    var urlSuffix = "";
    var slectedCategory = "";
    var selectedLevel = "";
    var selectedIelts = "";
    var selectedCountry = "";
    var selectedPtype = "";
    var selectedDtype = "";
    var selectedLanguage = "";
    var selectedRating = "";
    
    
    //Get selected category
   $('.categories:checked').each(function() {
       selectedCategory = $(this).attr('value');
   });

     // Get selected  countries
    if($("#country-search-value-unique").val() != 'all'){
      selectedCountry = $("#country-search-value-unique").val();
    };
    
    if($("#ielts-search-value-unique").val() != 'all'){
      selectedIelts = $("#ielts-search-value-unique").val();
    };
    
    if($("#ptype-search-value-unique").val() != 'all'){
      selectedPtype = $("#ptype-search-value-unique").val();
    };
    
    if($("#dtype-search-value-unique").val() != 'all'){
      selectedDtype = $("#dtype-search-value-unique").val();
    };
    
    if($("#level-search-value-unique").val() != 'all'){
      selectedLevel = $("#level-search-value-unique").val();
    };
    
    if($("#price-search-value-unique").val() != 'all'){
      selectedPrice = $("#price-search-value-unique").val();
    };

    
    // Get selected difficulty Level
    $('.languages:checked').each(function() {
        selectedLanguage = $(this).attr('value');
    });

    // Get selected rating
    $('.ratings:checked').each(function() {
        selectedRating = $(this).attr('value');
    });

    urlSuffix = "category="+selectedCategory+"&&level="+selectedLevel+"&&ielts="+selectedIelts+"&&country="+selectedCountry+"&&ptype="+selectedPtype+"&&dtype="+selectedDtype+"&&language="+selectedLanguage+"&&rating="+selectedRating;
    var url = urlPrefix+urlSuffix;
    return url;
}
function filter() {
    var url = get_url();
    window.location.replace(url);
    //console.log(url);
}


function toggleLayout(layout) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'https://example.com/home/set_layout_to_session',
        data : {layout : layout},
        success : function(response){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}

function showToggle(elem, selector) {
    $('.'+selector).slideToggle(20);
    if($(elem).text() === "show_more")
    {
        $(elem).text('show_less');
    }
    else
    {
        $(elem).text('show_more');
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.catparent-label', function(e) {
                $(this).next('ul').fadeIn(); $('li.has').removeClass('is-active'); $('ul.tree').addClass('has-selection'); $('ul.tree').find("label").removeClass('is-seleted'); $(this).closest('li').addClass('is-active'); $(this).addClass('is-seleted'); $('ul.tree').find("input[type='checkbox']"); $(this).closest('li').find(".catparent"); $('.BackListDisciplines').show(); StudyFilter(); e.stopPropagation()
            }

        ); $(document).on('click', '.subcat-label', function(e) {
                $('ul.tree').find("label").removeClass('is-seleted'); $('ul.tree').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',  !1); $(this).addClass('is-seleted'); $(this).closest('li').find(".subcat"); StudyFilter(); e.stopPropagation()
            }

        ); $(document).on('click', '.BackListDisciplines', function(e) {
                $('li.has').removeClass('is-active'); $('ul.tree').find("label").removeClass('is-seleted'); $('ul.tree').removeClass('has-selection'); $('.tree ul').hide(); $('ul.tree').find("input[type='checkbox']"); $('.BackListDisciplines').hide(); StudyFilter()
            }

        );
</script>
```

Comment: Then it's time to find some good tutorials that teach modern JS practices for loading remote resources. And it's also time to find some good tutorials that explain the difference between PHP and JS: PHP runs on _your server_ and nowhere else. JS runs on _your user's computer_ and nowhere else: PHP can generate JS code (because PHP generates the data, the server sends it to your user, the user's browser deals with it), but not the other way around (because PHP does not exist anywhere except on your server)

Comment: you mean is not possible with the code I have?

Comment: It might, but your code seems to bake php-generated content inside functions that assign values to DOM elements. so that's pretty weird, and almost certainly going to cause problems after initial page-load. Much better to let JS handle the JS side of things, have PHP handle the HTML side of things (with, at most, generating start values as consts in JS), and make sure that the JS can ask your server for new data, instead of trying to pregenerated data inside functions etc.

Comment: this is part of the code its a PHP Codeigniter that uses js right now is working pretty fine so if I change it to live load it may cause trouble?

Comment: got your point, seems logical and i will try to do that

Comment: Ideally, PHP doesn't generate inline JS at all: you write your JS the normal way, PHP generates your HTML with `<script async defer src="..."></script>`, and once the browser loads that page, and then loads the JS script, it has everything it needs to be a running webpage in the user's browser. The JS should be able to find everything it needs to do its job either in the HTML file. If it needs "bootstrapping values" then you typically have PHP generate a secondary .js file that has all those values, loaded as `<script async defer src="defaults.php?...."></script>` or the like.

Comment: okay now, how can I make it live load? do you have a solution for me?

Comment: not without a full rewrite: serious, find some modern tutorials that explain how to do this (not necessarily in exactly the way you need), learn how live loading works, and then apply that new knowledge to your specific code base. SO isn't a place to learn entire approaches, and in this case the solution isn't just "a few code fixes", it's a change in approach entirely.

Comment: thank you for your informations